# Youtube Videos become Choppy When Maximised [Ubuntu Maverick]

Tags: video, ubuntu, youtube

I just installed 32-bit Ubuntu Maverick 10 Stable everything is working fine, The system spec's are as below:

3 Ghz Intel DG101
512 MB RAM
80 GB HDD
256 MB Ati Radeon Xpress

the only problem is when the Youtube videos are maximized they consume allot of CPU plus video bacomes slower and choppy..... What to do? I have FireFox and installed the FlashPlayer 10 also. But no luck...Any Ideas how to fix? The videos work absolutely good in XP in same computer..... I have tried Google Chrome also but no luck in that also.... Any answer 'll be appreciated.

Comment: Recommend you ask this on http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: The problem is your graphics driver. You'll have to install the vendor specific driver.

Comment: Nopes its not the driver issue, i have compiz installed and it works perfectly alright! Every effect of compiz enabled and it works very very nice.... Its something other.

Comment: I have just tried opera , it does some better then those of Firefox and Chrome but its choppy too... By the way is there anyway i can get Drivers for ATI Radeon 200 Xpress ? for Ubuntu Maverick!

Comment: @Paul Dixon: there's no reason this can't be answered here, as it is not particularly Ubuntu-specific.

Answer (score 1):

To find proprietary driver for ATI card head to the [ATI download page](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx) and check if a Linux driver is available for your model. Alternatively, you can use Ubuntu's driver finder by going to System -> Administration -> Hardware Drivers.

If installing the driver doesn't help try the newest version of Flash by [getting it from Adobe](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/).

Comment: Finally i made it, all you have to do is to open youtube video any video then right click on video and choose Settings, then a dialogue box will appear, uncheck the "Enable Hardware Acceleration" from that box, reload the video and enjoy!! [SOLVED]

Comment: @Ahsan So you should delete the comment and post it as an answer. You are sure to get my vote :)

Answer (score 1):

Finally i made it, all you have to do is to open youtube video any video then right click on video and choose Settings, then a dialogue box will appear, uncheck the "Enable Hardware Acceleration" from that box, reload the video and enjoy!! [SOLVED]

Comment: This is not really the solution, only a hack that makes it not so symptomatic. The correct answer here was given in comments and by @phunehehe as an answer. You don't just need a working graphics driver, you need the latest proprietary ones and the latest flash player. Flash's hardware acceleration is way picker than compiz, it only cooperates with a few versions of a few proprietary drivers.

Answer (score 0):

He he... You guys are funny . . It s very simple. It will work in 320p when the screen is maximised. Change it from 480p to 320p which is near the volume control when the screen is maximised. All the best watching Youtube!!

Regards,
Aravindh :)